# About an example from a PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

This is an example from a PDE book. My question is how does it arrive at $u=f(y) cosx+g(y) sin x$? Is it by pure observation?

Comment: "My question is how to interpret $u_{xx}$" -- What do you mean by this? I can't think of a proper response other than "the second partial derivative of $u(x,y)$ with respect to $x$" ... which I imagine is obvious to you.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer sorry, I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show easily that

$$\Big(\Big(\frac{d}{dx}\Big)^2+1\Big)u(x,y)=\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+i\Big)\Big(\frac{d}{dx}-i\Big)u(x,y)$$

then we conclude that the function $v=(\frac{d}{dx}-i)u$ obeys the equation

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-iv\iff v=A(y)e^{-ix}$$
where $A(y)$ is an arbitrary complex function.
Then we solve again for the now first order equation obeyed by $u(x,y)$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-iu=A(y)e^{-ix}\iff\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(e^{-ix}u)=A(y)e^{-2ix}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(A(y)\frac{e^{-2ix}}{-2i})$$

which we trivially integrate for the result

$$u(x,y)=B(y)e^{ix}+i\frac{A(y)}{2}e^{-ix}$$
where $B(y)$ is another arbitrary complex function.
Finally we rearrange and obtain

$$u(x,y)=\Big(B(y)+i\frac{A(y)}{2}\Big)\cos x+i\Big(B(y)-i\frac{A(y)}{2}\Big)\sin x\equiv f(y)\cos x+g(y)\sin x$$

where $f,g$ are again, unrelated arbitrary complex functions. For the purposes of the book, it is enough to restrict the solutions to the PDE to be real, but the final form of the solution is the same.

Comment: I think there is a typo, there should not be a square here $$\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+1\Big)^2u(x,y)=\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+i\Big)\Big(\frac{d}{dx}-i\Big)u(x,y)$$

Comment: $v=(\frac{d}{dx}-i)u$ obeys the equation 

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-iv\iff v=A(y)e^{-ix}$$ Can you expand on the idea of getting this? How you arrive at the general equation?